# Deserialize JSON object to Generic list of Objects

Tags: asp.net, json, serialization

I have a `JSON` string like this:

```
{"FacilityID":63,
 "StartDate":"2012-01-01",
 "EndDate":"2012-07-12",
 "PrimaryChoices":[{"ItemName":"Employee","ItemID":107},
                   {"ItemName":"Category","ItemID":104}]
}
```

This JSON string is "generic".  It will not be resolved into a strongly typed object - but rather I need a generic `Dictionary(Of String,Object)`.

When I execute a command like this:

```
Dim ChartConfig = New JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject(JSONString)
```

I get a Dictionary as expected, but the PrimaryChoices item does not Deserialize the two ItemName items properly.  Is this possible?

Comment: It works for me. The `PrimaryChoices` property is correctly deserialized as an array of 2 objects; each containing a `Dictionary<string,object>` with 2 elements with keys itemName and ItemID.

Comment: I'm going to surrender.  Was trying to keep the object I resolved the JSON to a generic, but it's more trouble than it's worth.  Instead, I'm creating a strongly typed class and using the Newton.JSON tool:

JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of ReportParameters)(result.ReportConfiguration)


Where ReportConfiguration is my JSON String and ReportParameters is my new Public Class.